# Can't connect to docker daemon when starting a container, but docker info returns information

Tags: docker, ubuntu-15.10, eclipse-che

I've been trying to get eclipse che installed on one of my servers for the past few days using docker. I have my docker daemon running on a seperate screen with the defualt host of unix:///var/run/docker.sock (I did not set this, I only ran '**docker -d**'). Testing to make sure I can connect to the docker daemon, I ran 'docker info' and was given the standard output, no errors.

Upon trying to create/start an eclipse che container with the command '**docker run -it --rm -e DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock eclipse/che start**' I am given the error '*Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?*'. Curiously enough, no matter what I set for **DOCKER_HOST** in the previous command, the command will still run, even if the variable is set to nothing(e.g. '**docker run -it --rm -e DOCKER_HOST= eclipse/che start**') which leads me to think that this is the source of the problem. Also, upon running the previous command, the docker daemon does report some sort of action occurring in relation to che (although I do not really understand what is occurring):

```
INFO[0000] +job serveapi(unix:///var/run/docker.sock)
INFO[0000] Listening for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock)
INFO[0000] +job init_networkdriver()
INFO[0000] -job init_networkdriver() = OK (0)
WARN[0000] Your kernel does not support cgroup swap limit.
INFO[0000] Loading containers: start.

INFO[0000] Loading containers: done.
INFO[0000] docker daemon: 1.6.2 7c8fca2; execdriver: native-0.2; graphdriver: aufs
INFO[0000] +job acceptconnections()
INFO[0000] -job acceptconnections() = OK (0)
INFO[0000] Daemon has completed initialization
INFO[0093] POST /v1.18/containers/create
INFO[0093] +job create()
INFO[0093] +job log(create, 7a5d00f69586306f95e98f752fb84c9dfe8e5c959d66b35a8125934dbb174dfb, eclipse/che:latest)
INFO[0093] -job log(create, 7a5d00f69586306f95e98f752fb84c9dfe8e5c959d66b35a8125934dbb174dfb, eclipse/che:latest) = OK (0)
INFO[0093] -job create() = OK (0)
INFO[0093] POST /v1.18/containers/7a5d00f69586306f95e98f752fb84c9dfe8e5c959d66b35a8125934dbb174dfb/attach?stderr=1&stdin=1&stdout=1&stream=1
INFO[0093] +job container_inspect(7a5d00f69586306f95e98f752fb84c9dfe8e5c959d66b35a8125934dbb174dfb)
INFO[0093] -job container_inspect(7a5d00f69586306f95e98f752fb84c9dfe8e5c959d66b35a8125934dbb174dfb) = OK (0)
INFO[0093] +job attach(7a5d00f69586306f95e98f752fb84c9dfe8e5c959d66b35a8125934dbb174dfb)
INFO[0093] POST /v1.18/containers/7a5d00f69586306f95e98f752fb84c9dfe8e5c959d66b35a8125934dbb174dfb/start
INFO[0093] +job start(7a5d00f69586306f95e98f752fb84c9dfe8e5c959d66b35a8125934dbb174dfb)
INFO[0093] No non-localhost DNS nameservers are left in resolv.conf. Using default external servers : [nameserver 8.8.8.8 nameserver 8.8.4.4]
INFO[0093] +job allocate_interface(7a5d00f69586306f95e98f752fb84c9dfe8e5c959d66b35a8125934dbb174dfb)
INFO[0093] -job allocate_interface(7a5d00f69586306f95e98f752fb84c9dfe8e5c959d66b35a8125934dbb174dfb) = OK (0)
INFO[0093] +job log(start, 7a5d00f69586306f95e98f752fb84c9dfe8e5c959d66b35a8125934dbb174dfb, eclipse/che:latest)
INFO[0093] -job log(start, 7a5d00f69586306f95e98f752fb84c9dfe8e5c959d66b35a8125934dbb174dfb, eclipse/che:latest) = OK (0)
INFO[0093] -job start(7a5d00f69586306f95e98f752fb84c9dfe8e5c959d66b35a8125934dbb174dfb) = OK (0)
INFO[0093] POST /v1.18/containers/7a5d00f69586306f95e98f752fb84c9dfe8e5c959d66b35a8125934dbb174dfb/resize?h=66&w=230
INFO[0093] +job resize(7a5d00f69586306f95e98f752fb84c9dfe8e5c959d66b35a8125934dbb174dfb, 66, 230)
INFO[0093] -job resize(7a5d00f69586306f95e98f752fb84c9dfe8e5c959d66b35a8125934dbb174dfb, 66, 230) = OK (0)
INFO[0093] +job log(die, 7a5d00f69586306f95e98f752fb84c9dfe8e5c959d66b35a8125934dbb174dfb, eclipse/che:latest)
INFO[0093] -job log(die, 7a5d00f69586306f95e98f752fb84c9dfe8e5c959d66b35a8125934dbb174dfb, eclipse/che:latest) = OK (0)
INFO[0093] -job attach(7a5d00f69586306f95e98f752fb84c9dfe8e5c959d66b35a8125934dbb174dfb) = OK (0)
INFO[0093] +job release_interface(7a5d00f69586306f95e98f752fb84c9dfe8e5c959d66b35a8125934dbb174dfb)
INFO[0093] -job release_interface(7a5d00f69586306f95e98f752fb84c9dfe8e5c959d66b35a8125934dbb174dfb) = OK (0)
INFO[0093] POST /v1.18/containers/7a5d00f69586306f95e98f752fb84c9dfe8e5c959d66b35a8125934dbb174dfb/wait
INFO[0093] +job wait(7a5d00f69586306f95e98f752fb84c9dfe8e5c959d66b35a8125934dbb174dfb)
INFO[0094] -job wait(7a5d00f69586306f95e98f752fb84c9dfe8e5c959d66b35a8125934dbb174dfb) = OK (0)
INFO[0094] GET /v1.18/containers/7a5d00f69586306f95e98f752fb84c9dfe8e5c959d66b35a8125934dbb174dfb/json
INFO[0094] +job container_inspect(7a5d00f69586306f95e98f752fb84c9dfe8e5c959d66b35a8125934dbb174dfb)
INFO[0094] -job container_inspect(7a5d00f69586306f95e98f752fb84c9dfe8e5c959d66b35a8125934dbb174dfb) = OK (0)
INFO[0094] DELETE /v1.18/containers/7a5d00f69586306f95e98f752fb84c9dfe8e5c959d66b35a8125934dbb174dfb?v=1
INFO[0094] +job rm(7a5d00f69586306f95e98f752fb84c9dfe8e5c959d66b35a8125934dbb174dfb)
INFO[0094] +job log(destroy, 7a5d00f69586306f95e98f752fb84c9dfe8e5c959d66b35a8125934dbb174dfb, eclipse/che:latest)
INFO[0094] -job log(destroy, 7a5d00f69586306f95e98f752fb84c9dfe8e5c959d66b35a8125934dbb174dfb, eclipse/che:latest) = OK (0)
INFO[0094] -job rm(7a5d00f69586306f95e98f752fb84c9dfe8e5c959d66b35a8125934dbb174dfb) = OK (0)
INFO[0338] GET /v1.18/info
INFO[0338] +job info()
INFO[0338] +job subscribers_count()
INFO[0338] -job subscribers_count() = OK (0)
INFO[0338] +job registry_config()
INFO[0338] -job registry_config() = OK (0)
INFO[0338] -job info() = OK (0)
```

My previous googling yielded no solutions to my problem. I am in the docker group, I have logged out and logged back in, and I have obviously manually started the daemon. Another point to mention is that I am running on Ubuntu 15.10, and have ufw running (which I have tried disabling).

Comment: Have you tried `sudo docker run ......`?

Comment: @Salem I have, and it hasn't worked. Either way, I'm in the docker group, so I shouldn't have to use sudo anyway.

Comment: @scothampel Are you trying to access che from localhost?  What OS ver, docker ver, and che ver are you using?  I remember having some trouble with getting che running on either Ubuntu 15 or 16.  14 and 17 have worked fine for me.